# wpf listbox dataBinding

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, binding

i have a listbox who takes values from  Dictionary Size:

this is the Size type:

```
public Dictionary<string, int> Size
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
```

this is my listbox

```
<ListBox x:Name="boardSize" ItemsSource="{Binding Size}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate1}" />
```

this is my the associated DataTemplate:

```
<Rectangle Margin="8,8,16,8" Stroke="Black" RadiusX="45" RadiusY="45">
 <Rectangle.Fill>
  <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
   <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
   <GradientStop Color="#FFE24A4A" Offset="1"/>
  </LinearGradientBrush>
 </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
<TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" **Text="{Binding path=Size}"**/>
```

I have two problems:

1. where I putted ** I want the textblock text to contain the Size key value
2. how can I do command pattern when a button is pushed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `ItemTemplate`, the `DataContext` is an item from the source collection, so in that case it's a `KeyValuePair<string, int>`. So the path to the key is just "Key" :

```
<TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Text="{Binding path=Key}"/>
```

Your second question is not very clear, what do you want to do exactly ? Usually, binding to commands is used in MVVM: you bind to a `ICommand` property exposed by your ViewModel. However in your case there is not ViewModel, since your data object is a `KeyValuePair<string, int>`... Please give more details if you want a more complete answer

Comment: mate where were you an hour ago :) i found the same answer in http://windowsclient.net/learn/video.aspx?v=30804 
thank you ...
about the command i want this to invoke another grid (i want to make a bord game and this is my board size...) 
you can find more info here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846668/how-to-dynamicly-set-board-for-board-gamesize-using-xmal-in-wpf